# How to parse record headers in Kafka Connect S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I use Kafka Connect S3 Sink and it only writes the record's value to S3. I want to incorporate some of the record's headers into the final payload that is written to S3.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a Simple Message Transform to intercept the records and unpack the headers and "move" them to the value section of the record object.

In the source code of Kafka Connect S3, you can see the record value is indeed only written.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My colleague found a [recent commit](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/d2ce91f10a6b03da02e23b8701a4ad2906e7128a/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/S3SinkConnectorConfig.java#L169) in Kafka Connect where it looks like there's going to be support for it in the configuration. Is that true?

Comment: Looks like that got merged, so seems so. Personally, I'd been looking for that feature for a few years now